# Is there something like JavaScript's apply function in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, apply

In JavaScript, I can use `apply` to pass an array as arguments to a function:

```
var f = function (n,m) {},
    args = [1,2];

f.apply(null, args);
```

I now need to do something similar in PHP i.e. **pass an array of items as 'separate' arguments to a function**.

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: you can just parse the array as the argument

Comment: Sure, but it's much cleaner to pass them as separate arguments.

Comment: is it? don't see why, there's a place for both i guess.

Comment: Dagon: having worked on a big codebase that uses arrays pretty much everywhere for arguments, I can tell you it's a LOT easier when it's simple arguments. It's self documenting for one thing..

Comment: @dagon it's more work to type check and check for required params, give default values to optional params etc.... using arrays has several drawbacks

Comment: @NickyDeMaeyer even more work to worry about 2 year old threads :-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the function [`call_user_func_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php). Simply pass in your function (as a [callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback), usually a string with the function name), and an array of arguments.

Additional note: for static functions, use [`forward_static_call_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.forward-static-call-array.php).

Comment: By the way, rather than passing the string name, you can pass the pointer to the function directly: `call_user_func_array($callback /*, args */);`

Comment: Yes, you can use any [callback-type value](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback).